# Programmatically tab out of a legacy form field

Tags: vba, forms, ms-word, form-fields

In MS Word version 2202 (2019) I have a legacy form field (a plain text box) in a document that calculates on exit and fills a number of other fields with the result of calculations.

I'm looking for a way to use VBA to tab out of that form field and trigger the calculations. In other words, to function as if the user pressed the tab key when in the form field, exiting from the field, and triggering the calculations and filling of other fields.

I've tried the following code:

```
Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
```

but it doesn't work because the document is restricted from editing -- other than filling forms. This restriction prohibits this code from emulating pressing the tab key.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using `KeyDown`? Or maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

All you need after editing the field is:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```